# How to hide pickerview on storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, hide, uipickerview

I used a UIpicker in my iphone app, its filling half my screen up not allowing me to design my interface properly.

I have seen similar questions but I need to hide it on the storyboard/xib, not when the app loads.

Xcode offers a hidden option in the attributes panel but it just grays it out, and still clickable, so it does not solve the problem.

Comment: why dont you create it programmatically when/where you need it?

Comment: do i need to restart my project from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe would be better if you add it programmatically...

Check this: http://cocoamatic.blogspot.com/2010/08/create-uipickerview-programmatically.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, do I need to restart the project if I would like to do it this way?

Comment: You are welcome! No need to restart, just remove all the references to the UIPicker in the storyboard and UIViewController and start from that point...